# jquery slider not working at all

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

I'm trying to use jquery's slider and nothing seems to happen

any ideas why?

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <style type="text/css">
    #myslider { width: 200px; height: 200px; padding: 0.5em; float: left; margin: 10px; background: blue }
   </style>

<SCRIPT type=text/javascript>
    $(function() {
        $("#myslider").slider();
    });
    </SCRIPT>

</head><body>
<div id="myslider"></div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think what is missing is the theme/css file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.10/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
```

[I tried your code](http://jsfiddle.net/qGUJZ/) and it works fine.

Regards

Comment: if i want to change the appearence, where can i download this file?

Comment: Enter this [url](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.10/themes/base/jquery-ui.css) in your browser then save the file on your computer or elsewhere.

Comment: Zakaria, thank you!! :) it is an older post, but you have made my day even better for this post, thank you! :)